# SQLite one to many and many to many relationships between the tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create a table where BasicModel Table and ExtendCategory1 Table have a one to many relationship. BasicModel(One)->ExtendCategory1(Many).
Then ExtendCategory1 Table and Alarm Table have a one to one relationship. And Alarm Table and AlarmTimings Table have a one to one relationship.

This id my code below. But it's not working. Any Ideas?

```
String basicModelCreateQuery = "CREATE TABLE BasicModel" +
                    "(_BasicModel_ID integer primary key autoincrement," +
                    "CATEGORY TEXT);";
            db.execSQL(basicModelCreateQuery);

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO BasicModel VALUES (0, 'Category 1')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO BasicModel VALUES (1, 'Category 2')");

            String extendCategory1CreateQuery = "CREATE TABLE ExtendCategory1" +
                    "(_ExtendCategory1_ID integer primary key autoincrement," +
                    "_BasicModel_ID_TO_ExtendCategory1_ID INTEGER, _BasicModel_ID_TO_ExtendCategory1_ID REFERENCES BasicModel(_BasicModel_ID)," +
                    "NAME TEXT, DESCRIPTION TEXT);";
            db.execSQL(extendCategory1CreateQuery);

            String alarmCreateQuery = "CREATE TABLE Alarm" +
                    "(_ALARM_ID integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    "_ExtendCategory1_ID_TO_ALARM_ID INTEGER, _ExtendCategory1_ID_TO_ALARM_ID REFERENCES ExtendCategory1(_ExtendCategory1_ID)"+
                    "FROM_DATE TEXT, TO_DATE TEXT, ALWAYS, TEXT, WHEN_CREATED TEXT, " +
                    "WHEN_COMPLETE TEXT, REPEAT TEXT, SOUND TEXT, VIBRATION TEXT);";
            db.execSQL(alarmCreateQuery);

            String alarmTimingsCreateQuery = "CREATE TABLE AlarmTimings" +
                    "(_ALARM_TIMINGS_ID integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    "_ALARM_ID_TO_ALARM_TIMINGS INTEGER, _ALARM_ID_TO_ALARM_TIMINGS REFERENCES Alarm(_ALARM_ID)"+
                    "TIME1_HOUR INTEGER, TIME1_MINUTE INTEGER, TIME2_HOUR INTEGER, TIME2_MINUTE INTEGER, TIME3_HOUR INTEGER, TIME3_MINUTE INTEGER" +
                    "SUNDAY INTEGER, MONDAY INTEGER, TUESDAY INTEGER, WEDNESDAY INTEGER, THURSDAY INTEGER, FRIDAY INTEGER, SATURDAY INTEGER);";
            db.execSQL(alarmTimingsCreateQuery);
```

The error says duplicate columns. I dont know much about Databases. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review the answer?

Comment: Yes, below is the answer. As stated by @usajnf. Instead of writing this these two columns  `"_ALARM_ID_TO_ALARM_TIMINGS INTEGER, _ALARM_ID_TO_ALARM_TIMINGS REFERENCES Alarm(_ALARM_ID)"`
Simple write this `_ALARM_ID_TO_ALARM_TIMINGS REFERENCES Alarm(_ALARM_ID)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this part is being picked up as a duplicate column:

```
"_ALARM_ID_TO_ALARM_TIMINGS INTEGER, _ALARM_ID_TO_ALARM_TIMINGS REFERENCES Alarm(_ALARM_ID)"+
```

I think the second "_ALARM_ID_TO_ALARM_TIMINGS" should be removed.